# wp header logo over secondary nav

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I have tried a few different things and on the two websites I manage (one I've created to mimic a preexisting and the preexisting) I am having some irregularities with my header logos on WordPress.

On the site I have created, the logo sits fine with the application of :

```
header#top #logo img {
    height: 160px !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: -35px;
}
```

which seems to work, but when applied to the other site it does not?
www.yourproactiveit.com is the one where it works and
www.sydnic.com is the one where it will not go above the secondary nav, same code on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by adding

```
body header#top #logo img {
   top: -15px !important;
}
```

You can set `top: -15px` to any value you want, to pull to top use the minus "`-`" sign.

**Notice:** I can see in your CSS file that you actually have a `top: -30` to the logo element but you forgot to type the `px` units.

Comment: i know it blatantly says not to say it, but thank you, what a silly oversight, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you have not added px in top: 30;

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `top` css in your second website http://www.sydnic.com/

```
header#top #logo img{
  top:-26px;
}
```